# getting duplicate values in map for every key

Tags: java

I am trying to put all values in map and i have more then 20k values , now I am trying to put values in map by using idea as key 1 contains values from 1(consider i) to 1000 (i.e i*1000) but the output I'm getting contains duplicate values (key 1 & 2 have same values), not sure what wrong I am doing

here is code

```
 public class GetNumbers {

        public static List<String> createList() throws IOException {
            List<String> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
            Path path = null;
            File file = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String read = "";
            try {
                path = Paths.get("file.txt");
                file = path.toFile();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while ((read = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    numbers.add(read);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return numbers;
        }

        public static Map<Integer, List<String>> createNewFiles() throws IOException {
            Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<String> getList = GetNumbers.createList();
            List<String> list = null;
            int count = getList.size() / 1000;
---------------------------doubt full code-----------------------------------
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                if (getList.size() > 1000) {
                    list = getList.subList(i, i * 1000);
                } else if (getList.size() < 999) {
                    list = getList.subList(i, getList.size());
                }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                myMap.put(i, list);
            }
            return myMap;

        }

        public static void getMap() throws IOException {
            Map<Integer, List<String>> map = GetNumbers.createNewFiles();
            List<String> listAtIndexOne = map.get(2);
            List<String> listAtIndexTwo = map.get(1);
            for (String elementFromFirstList : listAtIndexOne) {
                for (String elementFromSecondList : listAtIndexTwo) {
                    if (elementFromFirstList.equals(elementFromSecondList)) {
                        System.out.println("duplicate copy");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                GetNumbers.getMap();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

if I change my Code to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            if (getList.size() > (i * 1000)) {
                list = getList.subList(i, (i + 1) * 1000);
            } else if (getList.size() < 999) {
                list = getList.subList(i, getList.size());
            }
            myMap.put(i, list);
        }
```

I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   toIndex = 25000   at java.util.SubList.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.AbstractList.subList(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.dnd.GetNumbers.createNewFiles(GetNumbers.java:43)     at
>   com.dnd.GetNumbers.getMap(GetNumbers.java:54)     at
>   com.dnd.GetNumbers.main(GetNumbers.java:69)

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What should be the values for the key 2? 1000 to 2000? Currently they are 2 to 2000.

Comment: @Eran can you tell me how to solve it

Comment: I can't if you don't say what output you expect.

Comment: I am expecting the output as key 1 (1 to 1000) , key 2 (1001 to 2000)...

Comment: A smaller but unrelated bug: "if (getList.size() > 1000) {...} else if (getList.size() < 999) {...}" <- If getList.size() is exactly 1000 or 999 no case will be true.

Comment: @911DidBush in last iteration the values are about 600 so its fine

Comment: @CodeGanja Actually, because getList never changes during its iteration the values are the same for each iteration (no matter if its first or last). Still thought I would point out that this code _might_ cause problems.

Comment: actually my file had duplicate values , and i thought something else is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the list into sub-lists of 1000 elements, you can write something like this :

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            if (getList.size() >= i*1000) {
                list = getList.subList((i-1) * 1000, i * 1000);
            } else {
                list = getList.subList((i-1) * 1000, getList.size());
            }
            myMap.put(i, list);
        }
```

or simpler :

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            list = getList.subList((i-1) * 1000, Math.min(getList.size(),i * 1000));
            myMap.put(i, list);
        }
```

Note that the indices are 0 based, so the first sub-list will be 0 to 999, the second 1000 to 1999 and so on.

Comment: not sure why this code is still giving me same output as `duplicate value`

Comment: @CodeGanja Perhaps you have duplicates in the original list (`getList`).

Comment: let me check that first

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a few things I would change but one bug is in this line

```
subList(i, i * 1000);
```

You are starting the list at `1 to 1000` first which ignores the value at `0` but on the second iteration you are doing `2 to 2000` etc.

Most likely what you intended was `0 to 999` and `1000 to 1999` after that.  BTW Performing a subList on a LinkedList is pretty inefficient.

I would build these lists as you read the file.

---

I would write it like this

```
public static void splitFile(String inputFile, String outputTemplate, int count) throws IOException {
    int fileCount = 0, lineCount = 0;
    // check for duplicates.
    Set<String> previous = new HashSet<>();
    // file to write to
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    // file to read from
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
        // while there is another line to read.
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            // skip duplicates.
            if (!previous.add(line))
                continue;
            // if we are at the end or haven't start a file.
            if (pw == null || lineCount++ >= count) {
                // close the old on if there was one.
                if (pw != null)
                    pw.close();
                // start a new file using the template i.e. where do we put the number.
                pw = new PrintWriter(String.format(outputTemplate, fileCount++));
                // we will have one line in this file.
                lineCount = 1;
            }
            // add the line.
            pw.println(line);
        }
    }
    // close the file if we had one left open.
    if (pw != null)
        pw.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // split the file into multiple files with up to 1000 lines each.
    splitFile("file.txt", "file-part-%n.txt", 1000);
}
```

Comment: you are saying that i need to create a new list when I am reading values from file,

Comment: @CodeGanja I wouldn't even create the list. If your aim is to create multiple files, I would create them as you read the source so you won't run out of memory with large files. See my updated answer.

Comment: that file had almost half duplicate values sorry ,

Comment: @CodeGanja what do you mean? do you want to remove duplicates? That would need 2-3 lines more code,.

Comment: actully when I converted `list` to `set` size got reduced by half

I learnt a lesson never use wrong `data structure`

Comment: @CodeGanja You can't always assume you want to ignore duplicates, but if you need to ignore duplicates you can use a set.

Comment: Thanks @Peter I still need a lot to learn , but thank you very much sir :)

Comment: @CodeGanja I have bee working professionally with Java for 17 years, and I still have a lot to learn ;)